# “IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 3”

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

When Loading an RGB image, and trying to transform it to fit the CNN requirements (which is: `[1, 3, 175, 175]`) on a custom dataset class, I get the error above.

### Thats most of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from skimage import io
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from PIL import Image

class projectdata(Dataset):
def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
    self.landmarks_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transform

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.landmarks_frame)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
    imag = io.imread(img_name) 
    landmarks = self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 1:]
    landmarks = np.array([landmarks])
    landmarks = landmarks.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
    imag = Image.fromarray(imag) # we do not expect an ndarray
    sample = {'image': imag, 'landmarks': landmarks}
    
    if self.transform:
        sample = self.transform(sample['image'])
    
    img = sample['image'] 
    label = sample['landmarks']
    return img, label    


transformer = transforms.Compose([
transforms.Resize(1,3,175,175),
transforms.ToTensor(),
transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))

trainset  = projectdata(csv_file = 'face_landmarks.csv', root_dir = 'faces',transform=transformer)
train_loader = DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batchsize, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
])

for epochs in range(2):
  running_loss = 0.0
  **for i,data in enumerate(train_loader,0):**
```

Error appears in this line: `for i,data in enumerate(train_loader,0):`
And follows on to this line: `img = sample['image']`

### More trials:

I have noticed (by printing the shapes and sizes) that this line: `imag = Image.fromarray(imag)`
Drops the `RGB` dimension and transposes the image. so Iv'e tried rewrite:

```
imag = np.transpose(imag, (1,0,2))
imag = Image.fromarray(imag,'RGB')
```

And without `'RGB'`. But keep on getting the same error. (And its dropping the third dimension)

Tried to `expand_dims` and change `'RGB'` to `'RGBA'`, and that resulted Errors:
"Too many dimensions 3>4"
And:
"ValueError: height and width must be > 0"